# Group by a column and display the value of the column that matches the condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to GROUP BY a column and if there are more than one entries for it, I need to display the one that satisfies the condition. If only one entry is there it should be displayed too.

```
ID  |  Name  |  GroupId
 1  |    A   |     x
 2  |    A   |     y
 3  |    B   |     x
 4  |    C   |     z
 5  |    A   |     z
 6  |    B   |     y

Condition: COUNT(GroupId) > 1 then display y
```

Expected result:

```
Name  |  GroupId
  A   |     y
  B   |     y
  C   |     z
```

I have found answers with inner query. Is that possible to do without inner queries?

Note: If there are two or more records for a name and none have 'y' then have to display 'x' even if not there

Comment: What if more than one matches the condition?

Comment: Sorry its  > 1 instead of  > 2. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
select 
  name,
  case 
    when count(distinct groupid) = 1 then max(groupid)
    when sum(case when groupid = 'y' then 1 end) > 0 then 'y'
    else 'x'
  end groupid   
from tablename
group by name
```

For:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name    TEXT,
    groupid TEXT
);
INSERT INTO tablename (id,name,groupid) VALUES 
 (1,'A','x'),
 (2,'A','y'),
 (3,'B','x'),
 (4,'C','z'),
 (5,'A','z'),
 (6,'B','y'),
 (7,'D','k'),
 (8,'D','m');
```

The results are:

```
| name | groupid |
| ---- | ------- |
| A    | y       |
| B    | y       |
| C    | z       |
| D    | x       |
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nuKijDuTF5XdmFf94wDn1X/2).

Comment: This: `select 1 from tablename where name = t.name and groupid = 'y'` is necessary  to check the condition that there exists at least 1 'y' for that name.

Comment: If I have few more columns, along with group id can I get that respective value of another column too?

Comment: If this column can be the result of aggregation, just like `max(groupid)`, I guess you can (although I can't be sure). If not then a subquery will be needed to join to the above query.

Comment: Understood. It isn't an aggregation kind of. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select name, case when count(groupid)>2 then 'y' else min(groupid) end as groupid
from tablename a
group by name
```

Comment: Will return (A, z), not (A, y).

Answer (score 0):

You describe:

```
select t.name,
       (case when count(*) > 2 then 'y'
             else max(groupid)
        end)
from t;
```

But I think you really want:

```
select t.name,
       (case when min(groupid) <> max(groupid)  then 'y'
             else max(groupid)
        end)
from t;
```