# Display the value of equivalent columns by grouping a column that matches the condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to group by name and if the GroupId consists of y then y else whatever is available and also I want the values for equivalents columns.

```
ID  |  Name  |  GroupId  | Associate
 1  |    A   |     x     |   j
 2  |    A   |     y     |   k
 3  |    B   |     x     |   j
 4  |    C   |     z     |   j
 5  |    A   |     z     |   l
 6  |    B   |     y     |   m
 7  |    C   |     x     |   l
```

Condition: Group By Name and if COUNT(GroupId) > 1 and if any GroupId is y then display y and respective Associate column value, else any GroupId and its equivalent Associate is fine

Expected result:

```
Name  |  GroupId  |  Associate
  A   |     y     |    k
  B   |     y     |    m
  C   |     z     |    j
```

Comment: This is my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475135/group-by-a-column-and-display-the-value-of-the-column-that-matches-the-condition and now I want equivalent column data too. None of the column are aggregate type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the condition for the value 'x' in this question (and it would not be applicable in this situation), so:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
select 
  name,
  case 
    when sum(case when groupid = 'y' then 1 end) > 0 then 'y'
    else max(groupid)
  end groupid   
from tablename
group by name
) g on g.name = t.name and g.groupid = t.groupid
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nuKijDuTF5XdmFf94wDn1X/3).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name
              order by (case when t2.groupid = 'y' then 1 else 2 end)
              limit 1
             );
```

This returns one row with a "y", if available.